# cargar archivo JS en Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Necesito saber como ejecutar un archivo `.js` desde la consola de mongo, mire que si este archivo esta dentro de la carpeta de `bin` de mongo no es necesario poner toda la ruta, por lo que estoy haciendo esto `load("mongo.js")`, pero me salta este error

> 2019-04-01T11:20:26.962-0700 E QUERY    [js] Error: error loading js
>   file: mongo.js @(shell):1:1

Ademas tengo duda si realmente desde el archivo `js`, estoy accediendo a la base de datos `email` creada en `mongo`, aqui el codigo:

```
// Iniciar una sesión.
sesion  =  db . getMongo (). startSession (  {  readPreference :  {  mode :  "primary"  }  }  );

userCollection = session.getDatabase("email").users;
// Start a transaction
session.startTransaction( { readConcern: { level: "snapshot" }, writeConcern: { w: "majority" } } );
```

Ademas también tengo duda de esta linea, porque lleva al final el `.users`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion [load][1] dentro de mongo shell:

```
load('./archivo.js')
```

o en la linea de comandos, como último parámetro de `mongo`:

```
mongo --port 27017 --host mongo.stack.com ./archivo.js
```

Es una buena práctica usar un path (relativo o absoluto) al llamar `load()`.

Efectivamente estás accediendo a la base de datos `email`. MongoDB mantiene las bases de datos como una lista. No hay niveles.

En cuanto a la tercera pregunta, la linea

asigna la colleccion `users` dentro de la base de datos `email` a la variable `usercollection`.